# Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' Invocation of init method failed; during upgradation of Spring5.2 x

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

**ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError**

**Please find Below error**

```
   ****2020-12-17 19:27:17,332 [main] WARN  org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in file [C:\Temp\Java8SpringUpgradation\target\classes\META-INF\spring\applicationContext-dev-db.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError
2020-12-17 19:27:17,347 [main] ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in file [C:\Temp\Java8SpringUpgradation\target\classes\META-INF\spring\applicationContext-dev-db.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
                at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1108)
                at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868)
                at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
                at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:401)
                at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:292)
                at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
                at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:952)
              
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError
                at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:282)
                at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:452)
                at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:889)
                at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
                at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343)
                at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792)
                ... 65 more
[WARNING] Failed startup of context o.e.j.m.p.JettyWebAppContext@3c3b7825,[file:///C:/Temp/Java8SpringUpgradation/src/main/webapp/, jar:file:///C:/Users/K/.m2/repository/org/webjars/bower/angular-ui-select/0.19.8/angular-ui-select-0.19.8.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///C:/Users//.m2/repository/org/webjars/bootstrap/3.1.1/bootstrap-3.1.1.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///C:/Users//.m2/repository/org/webjars/angularjs/1.3.14/angularjs-1.3.14.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///C:/Users//.m2/repository/org/webjars/jquery/2.1.3/jquery-2.1.3.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///C:/Users//.m2/repository/org/webjars/bower/angular/1.8.0/angular-1.8.0.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///C:/Users//.m2/repository/org/webjars/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.12.1/angular-ui-bootstrap-0.12.1.jar!/META-INF/resources],UNAVAILABLE}{file:///C:/Temp/Java8SpringUpgradation/src/main/webapp/}
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in file [C:\Temp\Java8SpringUpgradation\target\classes\META-INF\spring\applicationContext-dev-db.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
                at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1108)
                at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868)
                at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
                at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:401)
                at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:292)
              
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError
                at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:282)
                at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:452)
                at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:889)
                at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
                at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343)
                at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792)**
```

Please find Below pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>5.5.5_JS1</version>
        <properties>
        <aspectj.version>1.9.5</aspectj.version>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>
        <spring.version>5.2.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <logi.version>2.2.4</logi.version>
    </properties>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-maven-release</id>
            <name>Spring Maven Release Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.springframework.org/release</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-maven-release</id>
            <name>Spring Maven Release Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.springframework.org/release</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- General dependencies for standard applications -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.objectweb.asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.springsource.org.objectweb.asm</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.flexjson</groupId>
            <artifactId>flexjson</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- WebJars deps (replaces bower) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>angularjs</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars.bower</groupId>
            <artifactId>angular-ui-select</artifactId>
            <version>0.19.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>angular-ui-bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>0.12.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>pl.project13.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>git-commit-id-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.10.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
            <version>10.8.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.11.Final</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
         <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
         </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
         <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
         <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
         <version>4.2.12.Final</version>
         <exclusions>
             <exclusion>
                 <groupId>cglib</groupId>
                 <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
             </exclusion>
             <exclusion>
                 <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
                 <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
             </exclusion>
         </exclusions>
     </dependency>
     <!--<dependency>
         <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
         <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
         <version>5.4.0.Final</version>
     </dependency>-->
    <dependency>
         <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
         <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
         <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
         <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
         <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
         <version>3.2.1</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
         <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
         <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
         <version>18.0</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
         <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
         <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
         <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
         <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
         <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
         <version>4.2.12.Final</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
         <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
         <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
         <version>2.3.0</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
         <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
         <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
         <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
         <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
         <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
         <version>1.1</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
         <version>${spring.version}</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
         <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
         <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
         <version>1.5.6</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
         <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
         <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
         <version>1.4</version>
         <exclusions>
             <exclusion>
                 <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                 <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
             </exclusion>
             <exclusion>
                 <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                 <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
             </exclusion>
         </exclusions>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
         <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
         <version>${spring.version}</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
         <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
         <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
         <version>5.3.4</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
         <groupId>net.sf.supercsv</groupId>
         <artifactId>super-csv</artifactId>
         <version>2.2.0</version>
     </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
              <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.4.12.v20180830</version>
               </plugin>
                   </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: You are mixing Spring 4.1.3 and 5.2 jars. Never mix versions of jars for a framework. You are also mixing HIbernate 5.2 and 4.2 jars, another mix of versions of a jar for a framework. Basically your dependencies are a bit of a mess.

Comment: Can you please let me know which hibernate jars for spring 5.2 are compatible  i want to upgrade only spring framework from 4 to 5.2

Comment: To make matters worse you are also using `spring-data-jpa` version 1.2 which is based on Spring 3.1. Not sure what you are trying to do, but you need to really need to take a good look at your dependencies. Another thing I wonder why are your Spring and Spring Security versions the same? Those are different frameworks and have different release versions.

Comment: This is existing project  i want to modify spring version because one of the service is failing in preprod they suggest to upgrade spring version

Comment: When something fails, upgrading a library 3 versions is generally **not** the solution, especially if it was working before that. Nonetheless, if your dependencies were a mess before you should still clean them up because those are problems waiting to blow up in your face. (As you can see).